# PHP Echo out values of an array with ranges

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am still learning PHP and have a bit of an odd item that I haven't been able to find an answer to as of yet.  I have a multidimensional array of ranges and I need to echo out the values for only the first & third set of ranges but not the second.  I'm having a hard time just finding a way to echo out the range values themselves.  Here is my code so far:

```
$array = array(
    1=>range(1,4),
    2=>range(1,4),
    3=>range(1,4)
);

foreach(range(1,4) as $x)
{

    echo $x;
}
```

Now I know that my foreach loop doesn't even reference my $array so that is issue #1 but I can't seem to find a way to reference the $array in the loop and have it iterate through the values.  Then I need to figure out how to just do sets 1 & 3 from the $array.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to show the range on 2nd index, You could try

```
<?php

$array = array(
    1=>range(1,4),
    2=>range(1,4),
    3=>range(1,4)
);

foreach($array as $i=>$range)
{
if($i!=2)
{
    foreach($range as $value)
    {
    echo $value;
    }
}
}

?>
```

**Note:** It's not really cool to name variables same as language objects. `$array` is not really an advisable name, but since you had it named that way, I didn't change it to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this?

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either print_r($array) or var_dump($array).
The second one is better because it structures the output, but if the array is big - it will not show all of it content. In this case use the first one - it will "echo" the whole array but in one row and the result is not easy readable.

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution:

```
$array = array(
1=>range(1,4),
2=>range(1,4),
3=>range(1,4)
);
   $i=0;

   foreach($array as $y)
   { $i++;
          echo "<br/>";

     if($i!=0){ foreach($y as $x)
       {
           echo $x;
       }
                      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Range is just an array of indexes, so it's up to you how to your want to represent it, you might want to print the first and the last index:

```
function print_range($range)
{
    echo $range[0] . " .. " . $range[count($range) - 1] . "\n";
}
```

To pick the first and the third range, reference them explicitly:

```
print_range($array[1]);
print_range($array[3]);
```